# Синонимизация меток на тему [модули]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

У нас есть две метки о модулях:

- [модули](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8) (85 вопросов)
- [modules](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modules) (208 вопросов)

Надо бы их синонимизировать, главная - [модули](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8) (так как она на русском).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 230 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 208 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 203 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'modules': [modules] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 288
tag remapping of [модули] and [modules] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
21 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym modules -> модули was approved!
```